# React Native Expo can't connect from phone to laptop on same wifi

Tags: react-native, wifi, expo

I am building react native app with expo and I'm currently using public wifi because I'm traveling.

On the bus and in the hostel's wifi I've experienced an issue:
- Phone can't connect to Expo running on Laptop (same LAN wifi)

Comment: Try changing to tunnel, instead of LAN in the browser console

Comment: Tunnel goes over internet right? I think it didn't seem to work neighter. But I'll try next time. Do you know in terms of performance if it is slow considering you might be on a 3g-4g connection?

Comment: Your PC and your Phone need to be on the same network to work in LAN, because it uses your LAN.

I was teaching a course in my university and over LAN the traffic was being blocked, when changing to Tunnel it fixed.

The tunnel option creates a tunnel to exp.direct, making your traffic go over a proxy in the cloud. So i think changing to tunnel may solve your issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying many times to connect using the wifi, and also trying to see if Windows firewall has something to do with it, I finally found out what might be the issue and a temporary workaround.

Issue:

- Some routers have a configuration called AP Isolation, that might be activated on the router/wifi of the public place you're using, to avoid someone hack into someone else's computer. So basically no device on the same network can communicate with the other.

Temporary workaround:

- The only way I've got this working was by enabling a Wifi Hotspot on my Android phone and connecting the laptop to it. This means I'm using my phone's 4G connection for internet too. Expo seems like it needs to access the Internet and if you don't have data won't work.

The other way might work is if your Windows or Mac computer is able to create a virtual access point. So instead of connecting laptop to phone, you do it the other way around.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This worked. If you're doing this sort of boot command for expo, 
`REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=<ip-address> expo
start`

my ip address changed when connecting to the hotspot and needed to be changed.

Comment: When connecting to a WiFi network, you're asked (at least on Win 10) if you want your device to be discoverable. My problem was that I usually go with No when I'm using public networks. Switching that to Yes made it work. If you don't trust a network, it's probably better to go over Tunnel rather than LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run on a virtual device via expo. On my Macbook I run on iOS if doing work in a place where I do not have internet but on a PC you should be able to run the Android Emulator.

While this might not provide the not intuitive way of doing things as you'll be using a virtual device instead of a physical one, it still is very quick and responsive. Just know that animations may not be as smooth.

I fly frequently and running on virtual devices has enabled me to work when otherwise it would be impossible.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that's one way! Will try to install Android Studio and give it a try!

Comment: Hope it works out. Android studio can be a bit of a pain setup-wise, but overall it provides a good experience if you're on PC and don't want to always use your phone for testing.